# Why was て omitted in this relative clause?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

> 彼は、外見はともかくとして、性格が良く、信頼できる人だ。
>
> Leaving aside his outward appearance, my elder brother is a trustworthy person with good personality.

## Question

In my understanding, the sentence should be as follows.

> 彼は、外見はともかくとして、性格が良く**て**、信頼できる人だ。

Why was て omitted in this relative clause?

Comment: Hate to ask a very basic question like this to someone who has already been asking solid intermediate-level (and sometimes advanced-level) questions, but can you conjugate the adjective 「良い」 into all 5 forms?  What is the purpose/function of the 連用形?

Comment: I am going to up vote this for the effort involved in getting to this level. But , I agree with @l'électeur.

Comment: @probablyme, I have seen your mathematical prowess and it is second to none. Please continue to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postpositional particle て has some meanings. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148945/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A6/

て can be omitted in the case of［接助]1,2,5.
Your sentence is in the case of 2 or 5, so て can be omitted.

Case1: 学校に行って勉強する → 学校に行き勉強する

Case2: 頭が痛くて寝ていた → 頭が痛く寝ていた

Casse5:　大きくて甘い柿 → 大きく甘い柿

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find that it was personal preference of the author. The top sentence seems to sound more educated (if you can say that) as in using the「て」is superfluous. Other than that, both are fine and convey the same message.

Comment: @YasashiiEirian, there you are wrong. Both are correct grammatically and probablyme has incorrectly implied that one is not grammatically correct. Your call.

Comment: You mention the top one sounds more "educated", and (at least to me) the use of ともかくとして also sounds rather educated and/or formally written, that is, the top one would surprise me if I heard it in spoken Japanese.  Is there any difference in relative rates of use of these two modes (く vs くて for this kind of non-time-serial conjunction) in spoken vs written Japanese?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian,  Next time I will just post a few links and say here you go. That should be enough of an answer. The fact of the matter has nothing to do with grammar rather the preference of the author to not use the 「て」

Comment: @YasashiiEirian , its your choice. I am not one to argue. Cheers

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy, exactly, the top one sounds more bookish and as I was explaining to Yasashii Eirian it sounds more educated to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the page 148 of "A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar". It is apparently an intermediate grammar. That is why I did not know it.

According to the book, both く and くて forms can function as a continuative form that connects two predicates. However, く is used in written Japanese while くて is used in both written and spoken Japanese. く can also be used as an adverb.

For more detailed, read the book.